# The ID of my next Zoom meeting

Tags: mathematics

My friend is inviting me to a Zoom meeting. Rather the sending me the ID for it, he sent me the following 10 IDs. "Each of these numbers has precisely two digits which are identical, and exactly in the same position, to two digits in the correct ID for the meeting", he told me.

My friend claims this information is enough for me to identify precisely the meeting's ID.

Is it?

729 1151 7089

814 3636 0364

271 4326 9437

024 2314 5129

762 5773 4513

424 1826 0602

223 2282 3249

701 3976 2870

841 9061 4151

077 8546 6723

Comment: Do the other eight non-matching digits appear anywhere else (in different positions) in the correct ID?

Comment: @bobble They might, or might not.

Comment: How do you feel about the use of computers on this one?

Comment: @hexomino No objection to use of computers, but a solution with out computers is possible and desirable.

Comment: I am unsure how I misinterpreted the condition, but I find multiple good codes. Eg. 72246163751 and 72380665317, where every code you gave contains exactly two numbers that are correct and are in the correct position. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is

> Is it?

and the answer is

> no, it isn't

because

> there are $31786$ solutions in total. Here are some of them:
>
>
>  22195740063
>
>  22195740383
>
>  22191730724
>
>  22191740763
>
>  22196740783

I guess the clever solution should be an argument which proves this result without going through my bruteforce approach. However I really hoped that the answer were the opposite.

Or it could be that I seriously missed something (e.g. there are special rules for Zoom IDs)?

Comment: Another possibility: 221957400630000

Comment: @msh210 The [meeting ID](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362373-Meeting-ID) for Zoom can only be 10 or 11 digits long.

Comment: (re your comment to me) I don't see anything about that in the question. Is that common knowledge that everyone is supposed to have, or something?